# filter duplicate characters from array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

How can I filter 2 characters from the array string?

For example, I want to show only those which have two 'a'.

The result will be 'Banana' instead of 'a' in every string

```js
const fruits = ['Apple', 'Apricots', 'Banana', 'Watermelon', 'Strawberry', 'Peech'];

let filteredFruits = fruits.filter(fruit => {
  fruit.toLowerCase().includes('a');

})

console.log(filteredFruits);
```

Comment: At first you need to return inside the filter function to get a result. So (fruit => { return .... }) play around with this.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a regular expression which searches fro a letter and take the length if not null.

```js
const
    fruits = ['Apple', 'Apricots', 'Banana', 'Watermelon', 'Strawberry', 'Peech'],
    filteredFruits = fruits.filter(fruit => fruit.match(/a/gi)?.length > 1)

console.log(filteredFruits);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to show only those which have two 'a'.

Based on your requirement, the number of char `a` in `Banana` equals `3`. So it shouldn't be shown. Let's try to filter `p` char instead.

```
return countChar(charArray, char) == 2; // Adjust condition here
```

From the above condition, you can adjust as you wish, For example:

```
> 1 // when you want to filter string having greater than 1 char
```

or

```
>= 2 // when you want to filter string having greater or euqal 2 char
```

```js
const fruits = ['Apple', 'Apricots', 'Banana', 'Watermelon', 'Strawberry', 'Peech'];
const countChar = (charArray, char) => charArray.reduce((acc, curr) => (acc = acc + (curr == char ? 1 : 0), acc), 0);
  
let filteredFruits = (char) => fruits.filter(fruit => {
  const charArray = fruit.toLowerCase().split('');
  return countChar(charArray, char) == 2; // Adjust condition here
})

console.log(filteredFruits('a'));
console.log(filteredFruits('p'));
```

**Bonus**

In your code, it's missing `return keyword`. You can resolve by 2 ways:

1. `return` keyword

```
    {
      return fruit.toLowerCase().includes('a');
  
    })
```

2. shorthand, no need bracket `{}`

```
 => fruit.toLowerCase().includes('a');
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help ^^! @fahad javed